# Where do i get google-play-services-ads.jar to include in my project?

Tags: java, javafx, admob, gluon, gluon-mobile

I need to know where i have to get the google-play-services-ads.jar to include it in my project, so the ADMob banner can work fine.

Can everyone help me?

I'm implementing ADMob using this guide:

[Gluon mobile cross-platform adsView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132046/gluon-mobile-cross-platform-adsview)

Thanks in advance

Comment: What has changed from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44542177/googles-admob-library-integration-import-cannot-be-resolved-in-javafx?noredirect=1&lq=1)?

Comment: I need to know where i can find that jar, for all the rest it seems to work. I think was appropriate to open another question instead. But if you think is better i can close this question and write in the chat of that question

Comment: No, it's ok, the jar is bundled in an`.aar` file, here: `<ANDROID_HOME>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/<version>/play-services-ads-<version>.aar`. If you added `explodeAarDependencies` to your build, you should find inside that folder the `exploded` one with the jar file.

Comment: I've got this in the build.gradle:

    project.afterEvaluate {
        explodeAarDependencies(project.configurations.androidCompile)
    }

And i've added to the classpath the path to play-se‌​rvices-ads-<version>‌​.aar. Is that right? Where i should find the .jar?

Comment: When you run the `android` task, `explodeAarDependencies` should be called, and it will find the .aar file, extracting the jar from it. You can do it manually (.aar is like a zip), and copy the jar to the project, if the task doesn't work for you.

Comment: I've done that task but i can't find that jar. Where i should find the .jar?

Comment: Under `<ANDROID_HOME>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android‌​/gms/play-services-a‌​ds/<version>/exploded/play-se‌​rvices-ads-<version>‌​.jar`

Comment: There's no exp‌​loded folder in there. Where i went wrong with this?

Comment: Run the task with `--info`, and see if there has been any error in the process

Comment: This: <ANDROID_HOME>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android‌​‌​/gms/play-services‌​-a‌​ds/<version>/exp‌​loded/play-se‌​rvice‌​s-ads-<version>‌​.ja‌​r  was right, i made a mistake. If you can post this as the answer i'll be glad to mark it as answer. Thanks you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has a local repository where you can find Google Play Services dependencies. For `ads`, you can find the `.aar` file under:

```
<ANDROID_HOME>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android‌​/gms/play-services-a‌​ds/<version>/play-se‌​rvices-ads-<version>‌​.aar
```

where `ANDROID_HOME` has been added to the `gradle.properties` file, with the path to the Android SDK, and `<version>` should be replaced with the number of ads version, i.e. 9.4.0.

Adding `explodeAarDependencies` to your build.gradle file takes care of finding that `aar` file, and extracting the jar and other required files, into an `exploded` folder:

```
 <ANDROID_HOME>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android‌​/gms/play-services-a‌​ds/<version>/exploded/play-se‌​rvices-ads-<version>‌​.jar
```

You can find more about that task [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/02acf4df30c1180ef568627d18cec212c99f95a8/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/JFXMobileConvention.groovy?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default).