# Using Firebase in Gluon-mobile

Tags: java, android, javafx, gluon, gluon-mobile

I want to use  Firebase Database in the my **Gluon-mobile Project** , after Reading the  [Firebase Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup/).I tried to this make some modifications to the *root* level [build.gradle](https://bitbucket.org/guru001/firebase_javafx/src/096da91a5eb51cc4502b665ae0a89ff1b2e0863b/build.gradle?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) and *App* level [build.gradle](https://bitbucket.org/guru001/firebase_javafx/src/096da91a5eb51cc4502b665ae0a89ff1b2e0863b/SampleFirebaseApp/build.gradle?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) files.
Am trying to use [Firebase storge](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjC14yZiJPYAhXELI8KHURbCDsQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ffirebase.google.com%2Fdocs%2Fstorage%2F&usg=AOvVaw1rIkIFnQ-TiCErZxqKVecb) in my [project](https://bitbucket.org/guru001/firebase_javafx) and Here's what I Tried.

Controller class ***SignupController.java*** in package *com.application.control*.

```
 package com.application.control;
 public class SignupController implements Initializable
 {
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)
{

    if(Platform.isAndroid())
    {
        try {
          Firebase firebase = (Firebase) Class.forName("com.application.FirebaseInit").newInstance();
          firebase.startup();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Signup");
}
}
```

And the ***FirebaseInit.java*** which is in `android/java/` dir and `com.application` package which performs Initialization of Firebase Storage.

```
   package com.application;
   public class FirebaseInit implements Firebase{
   public FirebaseInit()
   {
   }

 @Override
 public void startup()
 { 
    Context context=FXActivity.getInstance().getApplicationContext();
    FirebaseStorage storage =null;
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(context);
    storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    if(storage!=null)
    {

         Toast.makeText(context,"Firebase Storage success",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(context,"Firebase Storage failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

***Firebase.java*** is just a Interface which is used to kick start Initialization in the controller.

```
package com.application;

public interface Firebase
{
public void startup();
 }
```

And on startup am getting these below Error on **Android** Device.

```
12-18 12:01:39.133  4279  4304 W javafx  : Loading FXML document with JavaFX API of version 8.0.102 by JavaFX runtime of version 8.0.72-ea
12-18 12:01:39.205  4279  4304 W System.err: Exception in Application start method
12-18 12:01:39.207  4279  4304 I System.out: QuantumRenderer: shutdown
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafxports.android.DalvikLauncher$1.run(DalvikLauncher.java:188)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$138(LauncherImpl.java:182)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$1(LauncherImpl.java)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$2.run(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err:    ... 1 more
12-18 12:01:39.208  4279  4299 W System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzca.<init>(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.fromResource(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.application.FirebaseInit.startup(FirebaseInit.java:21)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.application.control.SignupController.initialize(SignupController.java:36)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.application.scenes.SignupPresenter.getView(SignupPresenter.java:17)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.application.Main.start(Main.java:40)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$145(LauncherImpl.java:863)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$lambda$8(LauncherImpl.java)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$9.run(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$158(PlatformImpl.java:326)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$6(PlatformImpl.java)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$7.run(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.209  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$156(PlatformImpl.java:295)
12-18 12:01:39.210  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.access$lambda$18(PlatformImpl.java)
12-18 12:01:39.210  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$19.run(Unknown Source)
12-18 12:01:39.210  4279  4299 W System.err:    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:52)
12-18 12:01:39.210  4279  4299 W System.err:    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$157(PlatformImpl.java:294)
```

Please Enlighten me , how to use Firebase with Gluon-mobile.

Comment: You need to add the dependency to the build script class path: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'`.

Comment: after adding the dependency to _app_ level build script am getting this error `Cause: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!`  @JoséPereda

Comment: See the [documentation](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/4.4.1/#_android_2).

Comment: I have updated `compileSdkVersion` value (as in Updated Question),but Even after that am getting the same Error `Cause: android.compileSdkVersion is missing!`,  @JoséPereda

Comment: When do you get that message? Running `android`/`androidInstall` tasks? If you use `./gradlew --info android` you will see more details of the exception. I can't reproduce your issue, with firebase 11.0.4 dependencies but without code.

Comment: Am using Intellji Idea for Development , and on Gradle sync am getting this Error. @JoséPereda

Comment: It works for me as well on IntelliJ (again, I don't have specific code, but I can run `build`, `run` or `android` tasks). Maybe you can try with a new project (make sure you have the latest Gluon plugin), and then add the Firebase dependencies?

Comment: I have added the firebase dependencies ,`gradle build` is sucessful,But all the Firebase dependencies are in `.aar format` ,so how do I convert it to `.jar format`.@JoséPereda

Comment: Look for `explodeAarDependencies` in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43132046/gluon-mobile-cross-platform-adsview). Include `project.afterEvaluate` with it, and it will extract and include the jars from the `.aar` files.

Comment: Thanks @JoséPereda , it worked but am still getting this `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/os/Process` Exception on `gradle build` , Any Idea..and Here's my [project](https://guru001@bitbucket.org/guru001/firebase_javafx.git)

Comment: Are you running on Desktop? You need to deploy to Android and run it there. Once you do that, you'll face different problems, like you need the Android Context, and you will have to move your code to the Android package. See [Go Native](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/go-native) sample for that.

Comment: Yes you are Right ,@JoséPereda ,I've updated my Question with my new problem.

Comment: I think your `NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string` is the same issue I was faced with several times. I already asked a question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46819138/generate-or-import-android-r-java-file-in-eclipse-gluon-project and filed an issue for this: https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/issues/82/add-possibility-to-use-platformspecific, without any reaction so far

Comment: So , what should i do .Is it another way possible to use `Firebase` in `Gluon-mobile` or it's not possible ?

Comment: I was able to use Firebase Realtime Database in a Gluon Mobile App via REST: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start. But then you have to take care for user authentication yourself